Microsoft Purview Error when Create Information Protection Scanner Cluster
Im trying create Information Protection Cluster on Azure Purview (Settings -> Solution Settings -> Information Protection), but im getting error saying Client Error. Please check screenshots Here
Any help? I appreciate any guidance.
Thanks.

FYI this is off-topic here, as it's not a programming question. Looks like you already asked directly on a Microsoft-specific support site, which seems appropriate - it doesn't fit here though.


To configure information protection scanner in the Microsoft Purview portal or Microsoft Purview compliance portal:

Sign in using one of the following roles:


Compliance Administrator
Compliance Data Administrator
Security Administrator
Organization Management

Ensure the user who is using to create scanner has above roles, otherwise you may get above error. For more information you can refer to the below documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/deploy-scanner-configure-install?tabs=azure-portal-only#configure-the-scanner-settings

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/deploy-scanner-prereqs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/answers/questions/2112530/microsoft-purview-error-when-create-information-pr



Tks for your answer. I have these permissions configured and error persists. Anything more to do? Help you for your time.

@FDS - fyi your question is off-topic here, as it's not a programming question. Also, comments are not for extended discussion. Best to either ask your additional questions on the Microsoft support site you already posted to, or (maybe) move this to [sf] (read the guidelines first though).
